# How to apply 3D moving background effect using gyroscope in ios

Tags: ios, gyroscope

I want to apply a moving background according to device orientation. If device is held vertically upright an it is rotated around y axis then the background should move left or right according to the value of rotation.

Other icons on the background will static so it will give a 3d effect. For reference i need the exact same effect as shown in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=429kM-yXGz8

The code i have developed till now is:

```
- (void)updateViewsWithAcceleration:(CMAcceleration)acceleration;
{
    _accelX = ((acceleration.x* 0.1) + (_accelX*.9));
    _accelY = ((acceleration.y* 0.1) + (_accelY*.9));
    _accelZ = ((acceleration.z* 0.1) + (_accelZ*.9));

    [_backgroundShadow setFrame:CGRectMake(_accelY*50,_accelZ*50, _backgroundShadow.bounds.size.width, _backgroundShadow.bounds.size.width)];
    [_titleShadow setFrame:CGRectMake(_accelY*50, _accelZ*50, _titleShadow.bounds.size.width, _titleShadow.bounds.size.width)];

}
```

Comment: So… what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI: You're looking at the acceleration, not the gyroscope; try this instead:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cmmm = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init]; 
    if (cmmm.gyroAvailable) {
        cmmm.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;
        [cmmm startGyroUpdates];
        CMGyroHandler gyroHandler = ^ (CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
            CMRotationRate rotate = gyroData.rotationRate;
            NSLog(@"rotation rate: {%6.2f, %6.2f, %6.2f}", rotate.x, rotate.y, rotate.z);
        };
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No gyro");
        [cmmm release];
    }
}
```